# Scanning BLE devices on Android : Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

.
Hi! I am trying to scan BLE devices with my app but I have been unable to find any. The idea was to start an scan and find my nearby devices, which would be printed on the logcat of Android Studio. The scan starts without any problem but it is unable to find any BLE device. I have tried other scan apps and I am 100% that my BLE device is transmitting and under my phones range.

I have added the permissions in the manifest and requested them on my code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

My code is the following

class BleScanner(val activity: Activity, val handler: Handler) {

```
private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? by lazy {
    val bluetoothManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    bluetoothManager.adapter
}

private val scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
   
    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
        // Se encontró un nuevo dispositivo BLE
        val device: BluetoothDevice = result.device
        val rssi: Int = result.rssi

            // Dispositivo HM-10 encontrado
            Log.d(TAG, "Dispositivo HM-10 encontrado: ${device.name} (${device.address}), RSSI = $rssi dBm")

    }
}

fun startScan() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE)
        return
    }

    val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        .build()

    // Escanear dispositivos BLE por 10 segundos
    handler.postDelayed({
        stopScan()
    }, 30000)

    bluetoothAdapter?.bluetoothLeScanner?.startScan(null, scanSettings, scanCallback)
    Log.d(TAG, "Iniciando escaneo de dispositivos BLE...")
}

fun stopScan() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE)
        return
    }
    bluetoothAdapter?.bluetoothLeScanner?.stopScan(scanCallback)
}


companion object {
    const val REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 123
    const val TAG = "BleScanner"
}
```

}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var bleScanner: BleScanner

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val startScanButton=findViewById<Button>(R.id.startscan)
    val stopScanButton=findViewById<Button>(R.id.stopscan)

    bleScanner = BleScanner(this, Handler())

    startScanButton.setOnClickListener {
        bleScanner.startScan()
    }

    stopScanButton.setOnClickListener {
        bleScanner.stopScan()
    }

}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    when (requestCode) {
        BleScanner.REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                bleScanner.startScan()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have tried to change permissions, change the way on how to display the devices and no results

Comment: "I have treid to change permissions" - elaborate? I don't see you requesting BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission, and you might want to use precise location permission instead of coarse one as well. That way you are least likely to get devices filtered by system during a scan.

Comment: What target sdk have you set for the app? Android version 9, 10 and 11 require ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION as runtime permission while Android >= 12 requires BLUETOOTH_SCAN.

Comment: Changing ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION seems to fix the issue! Thank you all for your help!